# not being called: onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When my users click the login button I want to hit my webservice. I have the following code to do so.

```
public void onClick(final View view) {
  String orgKey = inputCompany.getText().toString();
  new getAppInfo().execute("http://example.webservice.com");
```

Here is my `getAppInfo`

```
   private class getAppInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String xml = null;
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Document doc = GetDomElement(result); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");
        getChildElements(nl); 
    }
```

The `doBackground` is running but the `onPostExecute` is not. I have moved it out of the on click and it has worked but I need it inside the onClick.

How can I get it to run the `onPostExecute` inside my onClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is correct you might be getting an exception in the background process, stopping the background thread. put a log statement at the end of your doInBackground or add a catch (Throwable t) to your try.

Have faith - it WILL be called as long as doInBackground completes successfully.

As an aside, you should do your DOM parse in the background as well - at the moment you are doing it in the UI thread which may cause ANR popups.

Comment: if the ocument is big you might also be getting an OutOfMemoryError - which you can also catch in Android (different to Java)

Comment: Also, make sure you have internet permissions in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute` will **always** be called once `doInBackground` is completed. Try to *Log* something in *onPostExecute* to confirm this behavior.

---

add a general `catch` statement in your **doInBackground** method.

```
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: doInBackground is completed. It still doesn't get called

Comment: It doesn't even go into the onPostExecute. Thats the issue. Its does the doInBackground but not the onPostExecute.

Comment: BigT, do you have a lot of `AsyncTasks` in your app?

Answer (score 0):

First, a general pointer - class names in Java are conventionally capitalized CamelCase, method names are lowercase camelCase.

On to your question - are you by any chance exiting the Activity or closing the Dialog that spawned the task? If it works outside that onclick handler, my guess is that something is destroying the Handler object that the AsyncTask is trying to execute that method on.

Try posting a Runnable (which executes the AsyncTask) on the current Activity's Handler.